# Некорректно считает среднее арифметическое

Tags: c, арифметика

Выдает в консоли ,при вводе числа 1234,результат 2.000000,когда нужно 2.5(числа после запятой я умею регулировать,но вот почему он округляет?)

```
    int main() {
        int x,sum1,sum2,x1,x2,x3,x4,compose;
        float ar;
        setlocale(0, "RU");
        printf("Введите четырехзначное число \"x\" = "); 
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
        if ((x > 999) && (x <= 9999)) {
            x1 = x / 1000;
            x2 = (x % 1000) / 100;
            x3 = x / 10 % 10;
            x4 = x % 10;
            sum1 = x1 + x2;
            sum2 = x3 + x4;
            compose = x1 * x2 * x3 * x4;
            ar = (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) / 4;
            if (sum1 > sum2)

                printf("Сумма всех цифр числа  = %d ", sum1+sum2);
            if (sum1 < sum2)

                printf("Среднее арифметическое цифр числа = %.1f", ar);
            if (sum1 == sum2)

                printf("Произведение все цифр числа = %d", compose);
        }
        else
            printf("Введено не четырехзначное число");


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте приведение к типу float: `ar = (float) (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) / 4;` Иначе сначала происходит деление в целых числах, и получается 2, а затем присваивание.

Comment: Благодарю,очень помогли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Старая ошибочка...

```
ar = (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) / 4;
```

все `x1`-`x4` - целые, 4 - целое. Значит, и деление будет *целочисленное*, с отсечением лишнего. Напишите хотя бы

```
ar = (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) / 4.0;
```

Comment: Благодарю,очень помогли,даже не думал в таком ключе,все грешил на указатели

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, принимая его ("птичка" слева).